# How do I write a hash function for an unordered_map that takes a pair as key, but return the same value if I switch the order of the pairs members?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create an `std::unordered_map` that takes a `std::pair` as key, and returns a `size_t` as value. The tricky part for me is that I want custom hash function for my map to disregard the order of the members of the key `std::pair`. I.e:

```
std::pair<int,int> p1 = std::make_pair<3,4>;
std::pair<int,int> p2 = std::make_pair<4,3>;
std::unordered_map<std::pair<int,int>, int> m;
m[p1] = 3;
// m[p2] should now also return 3!
```

This is not a clear cut MWE but it's a cut out of what I'm trying to do in my program:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>


class Point
{
public:
    static size_t id_counter;
    size_t id;
    Point()=default;
    ~Point()=default;
    bool operator==(const Point& rhs)
    {
        return id == rhs.id;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Point& P);
};
size_t Point::id_counter = 0;

class Hasch_point_pair
{
public:
    size_t operator()(const std::pair<Point*, Point*>* p) const
    {
        // XOR hash. We don't care about collision we're FREAKS
        auto h1 = std::hash<size_t>()(p->first->id);
        auto h2 = std::hash<size_t>()(p->second->id);
        return h1^h2;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    auto p1 = std::make_unique<Point>();
    auto p2 = std::make_unique<Point>();
    auto p3 = std::make_unique<Point>();
    auto p4 = std::make_unique<Point>();
    std::unordered_map<std::pair<Point*, Point*>*, size_t*, Hasch_point_pair> m;
    auto p  = std::make_unique<std::pair<Point*, Point*>>(p1.get(),p2.get());
    auto p_hmm  = std::make_unique<std::pair<Point*, Point*>>(p2.get(),p1.get());
    size_t value = 3;
    m[p.get()] = &value;
    std::cout << "m[p] = " << m.at(p.get()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "m[p_hmm] = " << m.at(p_hmm.get()) << std::endl;
}
```

One thought I had was to compare the id's of each Point and always use the Point with the largest id member variable as the first hash, but I haven't gotten it to work. Does it make sense?

```
class Hasch_point_pair
{
public:
    size_t operator()(const std::pair<Point*, Point*>* p) const
    {
        if (p->first->id > p->second->id)
        {
            auto h1 = std::hash<size_t>()(p->first->id);
            auto h2 = std::hash<size_t>()(p->second->id);
            return h1^h2;
        }
        else
        {
            // Note switched order of hash1 and hash2!
            auto h2 = std::hash<size_t>()(p->first->id);
            auto h1 = std::hash<size_t>()(p->second->id);
            return h1^h2;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Your original hash function is already ignoring order; you hash the two values separately and combine with `^`, so it doesn't matter which one comes first. Any operator obeying the commutative property (e.g. `+`) would also work (though `+` risks losing data in the low order bits and creating more collisions). You'd only need to order the sub-hashes if your hash combining algorithm was order-sensitive, `^` isn't. Your problem is that you need to make *equality* order-insensitive; even if you generate the same hash, that will cause a collision, but the equality test treats them as distinct.

Comment: Your problem isn't with the hash function.  Your problem is that `std::unordered_map` uses equality comparison (`==`) while finding a key, and `std::pair(3,4) == std::pair(4,3)` is not going to evaluate as `true`.

Comment: Define a class `Equal_point_pair` that does the comparison you want and specify it like that : `std::unordered_map<std::pair<Point*, Point*>*, size_t*, Hasch_point_pair, Equal_point_pair> m;`

Comment: Another option is to wrap the insertion and lookup processes such that a consistent order is always used for the points. I'm too out of practice with C++ to write up the code, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a custom class for equality testing:

```
class Equal_point_pair
{
public:
    bool operator(
        const std::pair<Point *, Point *> p1, 
        const std::pair<Point *, Point *> p2) const
    {
        // Verify if both pair are in the same order
        const bool p1Asc = p1->first-> id < p1->second-> id;
        const bool p2Asc = p2->first-> id < p2->second-> id;

        // If both point are in same order, compare same members
        // Otherwise, compare swaped members...
        return p1Asc == p2Asc ? 
            *p1->first == *p2->first && *p1->second == *p2->second :
            *p1->first == *p2->second && *p1->second == *p2->first;
    }
};
```

Note that the above code does what I think you want to do... Also I haven't tested the code.

Then your map would be declared like that :

```
using PointMap = std::unordered_map<
    std::pair<Point*, Point*>*, 
    size_t*, 
    Hasch_point_pair,
    Equal_pointPair>;

PointMap m;
```

By the way, not sure why you are using (nested) pointers...

Comment: This was the solution to my problem, thanks.

I'm using nested pointer because this code is a cut out from a larger program where this was the chosen solution, but yeah maybe it's not neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

@Drew put his finger on the problem when he told you that your issue is with `operator==` and not `std::hash`.  So, how to fix it?

Well, the obvious solution is to define your own type (which can inherit from `std::pair`) which defines `operator==` to work how you need it to.  Something like this maybe:

```
template <typename T> struct my_pair : std::pair <T, T>
{
    using std::pair<T, T>::pair;

    bool operator== (const my_pair &other)
    {
        using std::swap;

        std::pair p1 = *this;
        std::pair p2 = other;
        if (p1.first < p1.second)
            swap (p1.first, p1.second);
        if (p2.first < p2.second)
            swap (p2.first, p2.second);
        return p1 == p2;
    }
};
```

Note that this code assumes that the same type is used for both `first` and `second` (because that seems to me to be a necessity).  It could also be improved to do less work but I wanted to keep things simple (see Deduplicator's comment for a better version).

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jMpmAGvhQWuFX6at)

Comment: `my_pair` is not really a `std::pair`, despite looking like it. Thus, inheritance is plain wrong. Anyway, `return *this == other || std::pair(second, first) == other;` would be much simpler.

Comment: @Deduplicator OK, `derived_from_pair` :).  And it's late here, so a bit tired, I just came up with what I could. But I don't see any problem with inheriting from `std::pair` per se since you get to keep all its functionality (such as it is) that way.

Comment: The problem is the one part you change: The different equality semantics.

Comment: @Deduplicator Why is that a problem?  Perhaps I should choose a different name for the derived class to make the intent clearer, but that's all.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: @Deduplicator Hmmm.  But what did I break by overriding `operator==`?  (I'm genuinely interested.)  I mean, if you go along with what she's saying there you would never override anything (except perhaps virtual functions).

Comment: Well, when overriding equality, you expect that equal derived means equal base(s), though not the reverse. Yours is exactly the other way around.

Comment: @Deduplicator OK, I can see your point.  It's a question of what you want more then: to inherit (I would say useful) functionality from `std::pair` versus (maybe) violating the principle of least surprise.  So I'm happy to leave it there, thanks for participating.